# Apache Poi Performance Issues in handling Multiple Requests

Tags: java, server, apache-poi, streaming

I am trying to write the data from database table to an Xlsx File using Apache Poi. At first, I tried it with XSSFWorkbook. I wanted to write almost 1 million tuples each with almost 100 attributes. So I got OutOfMemory error on using XSSFWorkbook, since it loads the entire data in memory before writing.

So I tried using [SXSSFWorkbook](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SXSSFWorkbook.html). It supports streaming, so there are no issues with Memory Usage. It works great when there is single client request. To be precise, it took almost 1 minute and 30 seconds to respond (In case of a single client). I am using apache tomcat 8.5.32 server in my machine.

I understand from the apache documentation that the SXSSFWorkbook keeps only a specified amount of rows in memory and writes the others to a temporary file.

There are two parts in my code.

```
    SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook(100);
    Sheet sh = wb.createSheet();

    String name = UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-", "") + ".xlsx";

    try {

        String sql = "select * from users";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        System.out.println("Query finished");

        int i=1;
        while(rs.next()) {
            User user = getUserByRS(rs);

            Row row = sh.createRow(i++);
            Cell cell1 = row.createCell(0);
            cell1.setCellValue(user.getUid());
            for(int j=1;j<100;j+=2) {
                Cell cell2 = row.createCell(j);
                cell2.setCellValue(user.getUsername());

                Cell cell3 = row.createCell(j+1);
                cell3.setCellValue(user.getText());
            }
            if(i%40000==0) {
                Date mydate = new Date();

                System.out.println( (i/4000) + "% completed"  + " System date : "+ mydate.toString());

                out.println( (i/4000) + "% completed"  + " System date : "+ mydate.toString());
                out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() + " " + Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
                System.gc();
            }

        }
```

This is the first part of my code. This code gets the data from the database  (Data Streaming from database has been handled in SQL Query. So No memory issues here) and writes it to the SXXFSWorkbook, which writes the data to an intermediate temporary disk file. This part of the code takes almost 40 seconds incase of a single client request and almost 5-6 minutes incase of 6-8 client requests (Together). Why?.

Coming to the second part of my code.

```
        FileOutputStream out1 = new FileOutputStream(new File("/Users/test/Desktop/reports/" + name));
        wb.write(out1);
        out1.close();
```

This is the part of the code, where data from the intermediate disc file is written to the output stream of my response file. This takes almost 40 seconds in case of a single file and about 10 - 11 minutes in case 6-8 client requests. Why?

In Addition to this, the speed varies with the number of rows loaded in memory. For instance, in case of 100 Rows, it takes about 20 minutes to serve 6-8 client requests whereas in case of 10 Rows, it takes about 12 - 15 minutes for the same. Why?

Also, the response file for all requests are written simultaneously. Since the server handles each request as a separate thread, why does this happen?

Comment: Use a profiler to check? As per http://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10165 you ought to be able to write a large file with SXSSF in a second or two, not 40+

Comment: Yeah.. @Gagravarr That's my query too. Can u identify what could be the problem here?

Comment: Only you have access to your complete program and the machine it's running on, so it's something you'll need to do!

Comment: I am concerned with your code, if you're working with Java 6 and below, you should use `try-catch-finally`, read the section "Use a Finally Block" in this [article](https://stackify.com/best-practices-exceptions-java/). Check if performance gets better.